# Android Store Pin locally

Tags: android

For some functionality, I want to store `PIN` which is the user input in settings screen. I want to store that pin locally in mobile until app exists in that specific device.

I have used `SharedPreferences` to achieve this. Does this the good approach? or any other better approach?

---

```
SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("1234", YOUR_PIN);

// Apply the edits!
editor.apply();

// Get from the SharedPreferences
SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
int PIN = settings.getInt("YOUR_PIN", 0);
```

Comment: If I understand right, you just need to store a key-value until your app gets uninstalled. Definitely it's the way to go. You can also get the default shared preferences for your application (no need to provide a name) like this: `SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);`

Comment: SharedPreferences is fine. It's easy to use and does what you want so why not. Go for it!